# VBA code has Runtime Error with XLSM documents but not XLS

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

This VBA code is working for me in copying and moving XLS files but when I try to run it on an XLSM file it is telling me runtime error and is highlighting;

"CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Select 'Selects All Worksheets in Workbook"

Run-Time Error 1004: Select Method of Worksheet Class Failed

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

```
 Sub AutoUpdate()

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.PrintCommunication = False

Dim SystemPath As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim UtilityType As String
Dim ThisName As String
Dim FlattenedFilePath As String
Dim FlattenedFileFolder As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook 'Workbook Stores Workbook

SystemPath = Range("Sys.Path")
UtilityType = Range("Utility.Type")
FlattenedFileFolder = Range("Flattened.Files")
FilePath = SystemPath & UtilityType
FileName = Dir(FilePath & "\*.xls")
FlattenedFilePath = FilePath & "\" & FlattenedFileFolder

Do While FileName <> ""

Set CurrentWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName, UpdateLinks:=3) 'Sets CurrentWB = to that long name. This becomes the name of the workbook.
    CurrentWB.RunAutoMacros Which:=xlAutoOpen 'Enables Macros in Workbook
    CurrentWB.Save
    ThisName = CurrentWB.Name
        For SheetNumber = 1 To CurrentWB.Sheets.Count 'Counts Worksheets in Workbook
                If (CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Name <> "What If") Then
                CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Unprotect ("UMC626") 'Unprotects Workbook
                With CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).UsedRange
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Protect Password:="UMC626", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True 'Protects Workbook
            End If
        Next SheetNumber 'Runs Through Iteration
        CurrentWB.Cells(1, 1).Select 'Saves each workbook at the top of the page
        CurrentWB.SaveAs FileName:=FlattenedFilePath & "\" & ThisName
        CurrentWB.Close 'Closes Workbook

FileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you have opened a workbook which has an auto-open macro that selects a different workbook than the one you opened.  That would then cause an error when you select a sheet in the (now inactive) workbook you opened.

Comment: `Dir(FilePath & "\*.xls")`  - it's surprising if this gives you any files with extension xlsm ?   Or your problem file has a hidden worksheet (which cannot be selected).  What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: So, what's the actual error? And why do you even need to `Select` that sheet?

Comment: Also, programmatically-opened workbooks open with macros enabled, regardless of whether you invoke `xlAutoOpen`...

Comment: `Sheets` collection can contain charts. If you mean to only work with *worksheets*, use the `Worksheets` collection instead... and iterating the collection with a `For Each` loop would be much faster. `CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Select` does not "select all worksheets in workbook", only the one at index `SheetNumber`. With a `For Each` loop you wouldn't constantly be dereferencing the `CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber)` object...

Comment: @Mat'sMug I was originally going to say "don't use `Select`" (I actually had to edit it out of my first comment) but the very last step of the code is saving the workbook again with a specific sheet / cell selected so that it opens again in a consistent spot - so a `Select` is going to be needed at some point.

Comment: @YowE3K it's `Select`ing a specific sheet because the loop changed what the selected sheet was in the first place. Don't `Select`, and you're not changing the selection, and thus you don't need to reset it when you're done. Or, yeah, do it at the end, just before saving, just to be sure. That's fine. What's not fine is to `Select` in a loop just so an unqualified `Range` call can refer to the correct sheet.

Comment: Run-Time Error 1004: Select Method of Worksheet Class Failed

Comment: @MichaelDowney then @TimWilliams correctly assessed the situation from the start, and you're trying to `Select` a hidden worksheet.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I suspect the final one is to make everything consistent despite what the users may have done previously.  So the specific `Select` that is causing the current problem isn't required, but I think the last ones will be desired.  (The one causing the issue could be removed - but I was disappointed that I couldn't definitively give our usual rant of "Don't use Select".)

Comment: @YowE3K lol, that's probably correct. Except the pre-save `Select`s aren't the only ones, and all the others aren't justified. This code is as bug-prone as it gets.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Hey - Tim Williams' guess is **probably** right, but my one could be too!!  (Same error occurs if you select a non-hidden sheet in a workbook that isn't the active one.)

Comment: @TimWilliams how do I also select hidden worksheets

Comment: As others have pointed out you really don't need to select any worksheets.

Comment: @MichaelDowney (1) Your `CurrentWB.Sheets(SheetNumber).Select` and `Cells.Select` statements are not actually achieving anything, so can be safely deleted from your code.  (2) Your `Sheets(1).Select` and `Range("A1").Select` statements need to be thought about a bit - e.g. what to do if `Sheets(1)` is a `Chart` and not a `Worksheet`, or if `Sheets(1)` is hidden, or if the active workbook is not `CurrentWB` and therefore `Sheets(1)` is referring to a workbook that you aren't interested in, but most of those questions can only be answered by you.

Comment: @YowE3k Thanks I made a few updayes/

Comment: `CurrentWB.Cells(1, 1).Select` isn't going to work. A workbook object such as `CurrentWB` doesn't have a `Cells` property - that's a property of a `Worksheet` or of a `Range`.  You are going to have to `CurrentWB.Activate` to ensure that the workbook is active, then decide on which sheet within `CurrentWB` you wish to use (maybe loop through until you find the first visible one?  **You** will have to think about the rules you want to use) and activate it, and then select the `Cells(1, 1)` (or `Range("A1")`) of the worksheet you have activated.